# count method in 'if' doesn't work - python

Tags: python

I don't get it, I'm trying to count the 2 in this list and when it is like this:

```
hand=['D2', 'H5', 'S2', 'SK', 'CJ', 'H7', 'CQ', 'H9', 'D10', 'CK']
f=''.join(hand)
count2=f.count('2')
print count2
```

it works perfectly and it prints me 2 as the number of times the 2 is in the list.
But when I'm putting it in an if it doesn't work:

```
def same_rank(hand, n):
    if hand.count('2')>n:
        print hand.count('2')
    else:
        print 'bite me'



hand=['D2', 'H5', 'S2', 'SK', 'CJ', 'H7', 'CQ', 'H9', 'D10', 'CK']
f=''.join(hand)
n=raw_input('Give n ')
print same_rank(hand,n)
```

If the user gives the n=1 then it is supposed to print 2 because the number 2 is twice in the list and I want it to be more than one that it is! So why it doesn't return that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a string; strings are always sorted after numbers, so `2 > '1'` is always False:

```
>>> 2 > '1'
False
```

Convert your input to an integer first:

```
n = int(raw_input('Give n '))
```

Had you used Python 3, you'd have gotten an exception instead:

```
>>> 2 > '1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

Because Python 3 has done away with giving arbitrary types a relative ordering.

Next, you don't pass in `f`, you are passing in `hand`, the list:

```
>>> hand.count('2')
0
>>> f
'D2H5S2SKCJH7CQH9D10CK'
>>> f.count('2')
2
```

You probably wanted to pass in the latter, your function doesn't work otherwise.

Comment: Nope just a total newbie tried to pass my university exam :P I tried it and it still returns me: bite me  None
I don't get it even if I put a value on n at first place I got this error

Comment: @RedRose23: Ah, that's because you are passing in the wrong value. :-)

Comment: Oh look it's finally working after 3 hours! Even though it still prints None with 2 but who cares? Thanks a lot :D Ok now it doesn't even print None cause I change print to return in def. Oh yeah! You're awesome! Thanks :D

Comment: @RedRose23: `print` prints whatever your function returns. It returns `None` (the default). You don't need that `print` call, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is a string, not an integer, when you pass it to `same_rank`. Either use

```
n = int(raw_input('Give n '))
```

or convert `n` when passing the value:

```
print same_rank(hand, int(n))
```

or have `same_rank` handle the conversion:

```
def same_rank(hand, n):
    n = int(n)
    if hand.count('2')>n:
        print hand.count('2')
    else:
        print 'bite me'
```

Comment: I tried all of them but the it prints: bite me
None
and not 2 as it supposed to print. I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

n is string type please change into int
Working Code:

```
def same_rank(hand, n):
    f=''.join(hand)
    if f.count('2')>int(n):
        print f.count('2')
    else:
        print 'bite me'



hand=['D2', 'H5', 'S2', 'SK', 'CJ', 'H7', 'CQ', 'H9', 'D10', 'CK']
f=''.join(hand)
n=raw_input('Give n ')
print same_rank(hand,n)
```